# Conseguir o Start Address de uma thread de um processo e termina-la individualmente

Tags: python, c, c++, thread, processo

O que eu quero fazer é abrir checar se um processo está aberto, ver a lista de threads, identifica-la pelo Start Address, e terminar um thread específico do processo. Consigo fazer manualmente pelo processhacker, mas preciso de um script para isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei fazer um python, pois é a linguagem que estou mais acostumado, consegui chegar até a listar as threads do processo, porém nao consigo achar o Start Address nem terminar a thread especifica.
Seria possível fazer isso em python? Se não, com qual linguagem devo fazer? E como?

Em python para listar as threads seria algo parecido com isso

```
import psutil

PROCNAME = "processo.exe"
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
         threads = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
         for thread in threads.threads():
             print(thread)
```

Comment: Porque as tags `c` e `c++` ?